# Precompiled Views, generated by RazorGenerator, inherited from GlassView, being Unit Tested

Tags: glass-mapper

I am trying to Unit Test precompiled Views, generated by RazorGenerator, that inherit from GlassView, based on this article:
http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/unit-test-your-mvc-views-using-razor.html.

I have created a model using the answer from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658121/issue-unit-testing-sitecore-and-glass-with-nunit

```
// Instantiate the view directly. 
var view = new _Views_Components_QuickAction_cshtml();

//Instantiate a TDS Code Generated Glass Model
var model =  new QuickActionDatasource()
{
     Icon= new IconAnimated(),
     Link = new Link()
     {
         Text = "Link Text"
     }
 };

 // Build a Glass model to pass to View - this works if you're intention is to test the model
 ISitecoreService service = Substitute.For<ISitecoreService>();
 service.GetItem<QuickActionDatasource>(Guid.Empty).Returns(model);
 var result = service.GetItem<QuickActionDatasource>(Guid.Empty);

//Use Razor
HtmlDocument doc = view.RenderAsHtml(result);

// Use the HtmlAgilityPack object model to verify the view.
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.Element(".quickaction");
Assert.IsNotNull(node);
```

Currently this fails on GlassView in the InitHelpers method, on the call:

```
SitecoreContextFactory.Default.GetSitecoreContext()
```

Specific error:

```
throw new NotSupportedException("Sitecore Context Requires a Glass Context");
```

When it can't create a Context object from the GlassContextProvider.

What would be the best way to have the IntiHelper method initialize NSubstitute objects (i.e. an ISitecoreContextFactory), so that I can fake rendering? Can I substitute a GlassContext to pass through the MVC View rendering process?

Having the Views precompiled highlights Code Generation issues thrown at runtime. The Views are rendered via a Sitecore ViewRenderings, and are essentailly 'dumb' Presentation components with a datasource.

Answer (score 1):

I would mock ISitecoreContextFactory and the return a mocked ISitecoreContext and see if this solves your problem. You might have further issues if you are using Glass HtmlHelpers.

TBH I am not sure how easy unit testing the views will be with Glass since this is something we never considered being a requirement.

You can set the default static for the SitecoreContextFactory https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/master/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/IoC/SitecoreContextFactory.cs#L12

Comment: InitHelpers initializes SitecoreContextFactory via Default prop:
    
this.SitecoreContext = SitecoreContextFactory.Default.GetSitecoreContext();

How could I inject an ISitecoreContextFactory in there? Can't think of a way using Reflection...? Any other injection points?